# CodeIgniter and phpmailer

Tags: codeigniter, configuration, phpmailer

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.3 and PHPMailer (https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer).
I have a problem with the configuration because it does not send e-mails.

This is my config file:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'mail.skins4points.pl';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'noreply@skins4points.pl';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'mypass';
$config['smtp_port']        = 587;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;                        // (in seconds)
$config['smtp_crypto']      = '';                       // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
$config['smtp_debug']       = 0;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
$config['charset']          = null;                     // 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', ...; NULL (preferable) means config_item('charset'), i.e. the character set of the site.
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; on PHPMailer useragent NULL is a possible option, it means that X-priority header is not set at all, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/449
$config['crlf']             = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['newline']          = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
$config['encoding']         = '8bit';                   // The body encoding. For CodeIgniter: '8bit' or '7bit'. For PHPMailer: '8bit', '7bit', 'binary', 'base64', or 'quoted-printable'.
```

I am using the email account you set up with hekko.pl
Here sample configuration mail client: http://www.pomoc.hekko.pl/content/28/53/pl/konfiguracja-poczty-w-mozilla-thunderbird.html

Comment: If this is the valid password, please remove it from question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `smtp_crypto` needs to be `tls` if you're talking to port 587.

Comment: OK, so set `smtp_debug` to 4 and see what's going on.

Comment: `2015-12-31 11:45:05 Connection: opening to ssl://mail.skins4points.pl:587, timeout=5, options=array ( ) 2015-12-31 11:45:05 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-12-31 11:45:05 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

Comment: That says that you've still got `smtp_crypto` set to 'ssl'. It needs to be 'tls'. Telnet to that port works fine, but you can't talk implicit ssl to a port expecting explicit. The guide has more info.

Comment: http://wklejto.pl/txt244046 | http://www.wklejto.pl/txt244047 | http://www.wklejto.pl/txt244048